# Spring./Liquibase liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: spring, oracle, jhipster

I had copied my jhipster project from work to my laptop in order to do some stuff.However, when I run the project with command *gradle bootRun* , I get this error:

```
liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set config/liquibase/changelog/20180223200132_added_entity_TipoMoneda.xml::20180223200132-1::jhipster:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-01843: not a valid month
```

This is the query it executes :

```
[Failed SQL: INSERT INTO SISFACTDEV.T_M_TIPOMONEDA (id, codigo, abreviatura, denominacion, createdby, createdDate, lastmodifiedby, lastmodifieddate, estado) VALUES ('1', 'PEN', 'S/.', 'SOLES', 'admin', to_timestamp('0022-04-10 11:16:06.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'), 'admin', '16-10-2018 11:16:06 AM', '1')]
```

I believe it might be because, at work, the OS is Windows 10 spanish and laptop is in english. I really don't have a clue about it .Everything is pretty much the same.

Comment: Why are you passing string literal `'16-10-2018 11:16:06 AM'` while in another column there is `to_timestamp('0022-04-10 11:16:06.000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')`?

Comment: @lad2025 I guess framework itself does it for me. That's why I am asking if there's any configuration to it, so that conflict doesn't happen.